PIC Schematic File Format
I'm trying to open some quite old schematics (I think around 1989) that have the file extension ".pic" and am stuck as to how to read that. They're not PIC files from PCPaint although they are originally from a DOS system. If anyone has any idea any help would be appreciated.
This is a dump of the first 128 octets of one of the files. The full file can be found here
00000000  2b 01 46 59 46 59 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |+.FYFY..........|
00000010  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  01 00 00 01 00 00 01 00  00 01 00 00 01 00 00 01  |................|
00000050  00 00 01 00 00 01 00 00  01 00 00 01 00 00 01 00  |................|
00000060  00 01 00 00 01 00 00 01  00 00 27 00 55 0a 00 07  |..........'.U...|
00000070  00 e0 00 03 80 55 05 00  01 e0 00 0e 55 03 00 0f  |.....U......U...|


Are you able to provide a hex dump of the first few bytes?

added it in. also a link to the file if you want it

@nxe The link requires a sign in to download. Please make it available without login.

should be okay now

That might not be a schematic.  It looks like a hex file containing the code.
